# How far out of order should I expect UDP packets to be?

Tags: network-programming, udp, packets

Under normal circumstances, what should I expect the worse case scenario to be for out of order UDP packets?

I'm currently tagging each packet with two bytes (a 0 to 65535 number) to keep track of the order.  Is this enough or too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be plenty, I have never seen more then 3-4 out of order UDP packets, you could get away with a single byte to track it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the RFC 3208 you can target the last two packets being out of order.

Worst case would by definition be unlimited and such you are better off treating a third out of sequence packet as data loss.

> In all cases, receivers SHOULD temper
> the initiation of NAK    generation to
> account for simple mis-ordering
> introduced by the    network.  A
> possible mechanism to achieve this is
> to assume loss only    after the
> reception of N packets with sequence
> numbers higher than    those of the
> (assumed) lost packets.  A possible
> value for N is 2.    This method
> SHOULD be complemented with a timeout
> based mechanism    that handles the
> loss of the last packet before a pause
> in the    transmission of the data
> stream.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3208